# Why does Pandas series.str.contains method not detect match when there is a leading space?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, contains

I want to find all index values that contain the string `' (target)'`.

Example:

```
index = pd.Index(['TIC7201-PV (target)', 'TIC7202-PV', 'TIC7203-PV'])
print(index.str.contains(' (target)'))
```

What I get:

```
[False False False]
```

What I expected:

```
[ True False False]
```

For comparison:

```
print(index.str.contains('(target)'))
print(index.str.endswith(' (target)'))
```

produces:

```
[ True False False]
[ True False False]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, the default setting for the `regex` argument, is `True`.

- With regex, `(...)` means capture everything inside, so it's trying to find `' target'` instead of `' (target)'`
- The options to resolve the issue are:

  - Set `regex=False`
  - Escape the parenthesis with `\(...\)`

Therefore, to get the desired behavior, there are two options:

```
# 1
index.str.contains(' (target)',regex=False)

# 2
index.str.contains(r' \(target\)')
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass `regex` False , `()` here is regex style

```
index.str.contains(' (target)',regex=False)
Out[103]: array([ True, False, False])
```